# ¿How Preventing FOSUserBundle , realize automatic logon , when the FOSUserBundle register user?

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

What happens is that in my application, only the administrator user can add new users, but when I create a new one, the current session becomes automatically or log in with the new user. I thank who can explain how to avoid that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear - please add some **details** (or code).
You added tag `FOSUserBundle` but not said how you use it...

If I understand correctly - check this:

1. If you create new `User` use `UserManager` [here is explained](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html)
2. Second - When `User` is created (by RegistrationController), this bundle fire many [events - check it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html)

Im sure You used normal registration method instead of `UserManager` createUser method or some other magic.
Remember that If you need prevent autologin for implemented registration action, you can extend this bundle and [override Controller](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)

**Important**: Even If it helped ADD more exmplanation to your question (it can help other users)